# Why does claudia.js fail package validation when using nconf in a specific way?

Tags: node.js, claudiajs, nconf, claudia.js

I am using `nconf` in a NodeJS project, which I want to deploy to AWS Lambda using claudia.js. I have followed this [example](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781783282494/1/ch01lvl1sec15/configuring-express-with-nconf):

```
const path = require('path');
const nconf = require('nconf');

function Configuration(){
    nconf.argv().env({ lowerCase: true, separator: '_' });

    let defaultJsonPath = path.join(__dirname, 'default.json');
    console.log(`Using default config at ${defaultJsonPath}`);

    nconf.file("default", defaultJsonPath);
}

Configuration.prototype.get = function(key) {
    return nconf.get(key);
};

module.exports = new Configuration();
```

This code works perfectly fine when testing on my local machine using `claudia-local-api`.

However, when I try to deploy to Lambda using `claudia create ..` it simply stops at `validating package` without any errors.

```
claudia create --verbose --profile wgmtest --version dev --region eu-west-1 --api-module app
packaging files npm install -q --no-audit --production
npm WARN claudia@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN claudia@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 21 packages from 18 contributors in 0.339s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
validating package
5.12.0
```

If I export a `class` instead of a `function`, the `claudia create` command works fine (see below). I'd like to understand what the issue is here, or at least how I can get some additional log output of the problem.

```
const path = require('path');
const nconf = require('nconf');

class Configuration {
    constructor() {
        nconf.argv().env({ lowerCase: true, separator: '_' });

        let defaultJsonPath = path.join(__dirname, 'default.json');
        console.log(`Using default config at ${defaultJsonPath}`);

        nconf.file("default", defaultJsonPath);
    }

    static get(key) {
        return nconf.get(key);
    }
}

module.exports = Configuration;
```